# How is Google Smart Lock different from the previous password management mechanism in Chrome?

Tags: google, chrome

I am seeing a lot of hype about [Smart Lock](https://get.google.com/smartlock/) from Google. How does it differ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the aspects of Smart Lock is the ability to have trusted devices.  For example, you can set your smartwatch as a trusted device for your phone, and then as long as the watch is within range, you don't need to enter a pin on your phone.  Seems a bit risky to me, so I don't use this functionality.

Other than that, it's pretty similar.  It can work with other apps as well as the Chrome browser though as well.  Not quite sure how this works, but it does say "certain mobile apps", so probably not in a very generic way.